# Javascript I can take Filelist but I cant take file

Tags: javascript

I want take file from filelist but I cant take. How can I make

**FileList (inputs[key].files)**

[image]

**FileList (inputs[key].files[0])**

[image]

```js
var inputs;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;

for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var userid = document.querySelector('.userid').innerHTML;
    var raffleid = this.id;
    var finish = this.value;
    if (finish) {
      postFinish(userid, raffleid, finish)
    }
    for (var key in inputs) {
      var value = inputs[key].value;
      var file = inputs[key].files;
      var name = inputs[key].name;
      if (value) {
        console.log('file: ', file)
        postData(raffleid, name, value, userid, file)
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: You don't have any button elements, but because your for loop comparisation is wrong the loop iterates one time to many anyway. `i <= buttonsCount ` should be `i < buttonsCount` because when i = `0` and buttonCount = `0` then you don't want it to iterate.

Comment: Never use `for in` style iteration on `Array` class objects!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your code is working and you just want to access the Object?

Then try this:

```
const myArray = Object.values(FileList)
```

This returns an array of Objects, which you could access with

```
myArray[0]
```

Comment: Thats not working. Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FileList' of null